How can I parse the TLS handshake in NodeJS?
I want to know how to parse the TLS handshake data in NodeJs. I've been trying to calculate Ja3, Ja4 fingerprints from scratch by capturing the TLS client hello packet. But I don't know how to parse the data to a readable Object like tls.cipher and more...
I want to know if there is any library that can do this or if you wrote a script to parse in the past if you could share that would be a great help
Thanks
I tried to parse it myself with the help of "read-tls-client-hello" node library. But I don't have much experience with Buffer and Bytes types of data
